# Add custom name on items created through commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon a villager who is buying 4 iron and selling an iron pick that can destroy iron and gold blocks. How can I add onto this command to give this pickaxe a custom nametag

```
/summon Villager ~-1 ~ ~3 {CustomName:Leroy,CustomNameVisible:0,NoAI:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:iron_ingot,Count:4,Damage:#},buyB:{id:#,Count:#,Damage:#},sell:{id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1,Damage:#,tag:{CanDestroy:["minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:gold_block"]}}}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
/summon Villager ~-1 ~ ~3 {CustomName:Leroy,CustomNameVisible:0,NoAI:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:iron_ingot,Count:4,Damage:#},buyB:{id:#,Count:#,Damage:#},sell:{id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1,Damage:#,tag:{CanDestroy:["minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:gold_block"]Display:{Name:"Weak iron pickaxe"}}}}]}}
```

Comment: if you could add a bit of explanation as to why it works, that would probably be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple things wrong with the command: the strings needed quotes, The unneeded attributes were removed, some things needed the `minecraft:` namespace, and the display tag was changed to show the custom name. The `Damage` attribute can be changed to make the pickaxe have more or less duribility

```
/summon Villager ~-1 ~ ~3 {CustomName:"Leroy",CustomNameVisible:0,NoAI:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot",Count:4},sell:{id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe",Count:1,Damage:200,tag:{CanDestroy:["minecraft:iron_block","minecraft:gold_block"],display:{Name:"Weak iron pickaxe"}}}}]}}
```

I have run this command in minecraft 1.9, and it seems to work, but if there are any problems please leave a comment.

Comment: A few of the things you've stated as required are actually not in this case. Strings only need quotes for very few situations, such as when the value would otherwise be seen as a different datatype or if a comma were meant to be part of the value. Adding the namespace is not necessary in creation-based commands (like `/summon`) because it will be automatically defaulted to the "minecraft" namespace. These particular changes do not fix the command, though their usage is still best practice.